# I m not able to click on a button in a web page using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

What is wrong in the below code

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://x.x.x.x/html/load.jsp")
elm1 = driver.find_element_by_link_text("load")
time.sleep(10)
elm1.click()
time.sleep(30)
driver.close()
```

The page source is

```
<body>   
<div class="formcenterdiv">
    <form class="form" action="../load" method="post">
      <header class="formheader">Loader</header>
      <div align="center"><button class="formbutton">load</button></div>
    </form>   
</div>


</body></html>
```

I want to click on button load. when I ran the above code getting this error
**selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: load**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using Xpath?

As the OP said, `find_elements_by_link_text` works on `a` tags only:
Below code might help you out

```
driver.get_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/form/div/button")
```

Answer (score 2):

As the [documentation says](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text), `find_elements_by_link_text` only works on `a` tags:

> Use this when you know link text used within an anchor tag. With this
>   strategy, the first element with the link text value matching the
>   location will be returned. If no element has a matching link text
>   attribute, a NoSuchElementException will be raised.

The solution is to use a different selector like `find_element_by_class_name`:

```
elm1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('formbutton')
```